# Shadow Map too big

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow-mapping

All is OK in the shader map texture, but the is scaled (too big).

The coord texture:

mat4 bias = mat4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,   0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

ShadowCoord = bias * projMatrix * viewModelMatrix * vec4(position,1);

Why in another example the textureMap coord is:

ShadowCoord = bias * projMatrix * viewModelMatrix * ViewMatrixInverse;

And another:

ShadowCoord = bias * projMatrix * viewModelMatrix * ModelMatrixRenderObject  * vec4(position,1);

Does anyone can explain the differences? and Why do my Texture Map is scaled?

Comment: We can only guess at what those matrices mean to the examples that use them. Not without actually seeing those examples.

Comment: Shouldn't you be multiplying the shadow coord by the view matrix for the light source?

Comment: Also, are you doing the perspective division in the fragment shader? Everything else looks fine.